# Recovering local files after Pycharm 'Undo Commit' Error

Tags: github, pycharm

I feel a very unique and stupid scenario.

I work within a team using a shared Github repository, just for our SQL code for BAU tasks and the like as a way to save/share our work. I had been using Pycharm community version to push these files into the github repository. For a while I haven't been able to update the master branch due to an issue (now resolved) , meaning I had a few files sitting in the local pycharm folder in a pre commit stage.

I went to commit after updating my branch but the push would fail, seems a large file had been put in the wrong folder. I tried to delete the file from the local folder, create another commit and push, but same issue came up. So I undid the commits via Pycharm, thinking that would allow me to delete the large file and then just push one commit without the file.

In a stupid moment it was this time i chose to update Pycharm as my tech support team had told me too due to being on version 2021 not 2022. I deleted the 2021 version but kept the cache. I now find myself in a position with all my files that had been in the 'pre' commit stage deleted from my local, and Pycharm has no log history or change history of any of the commits failed pushes i tried this morning.

Does anyone know how I can recover my files?

I have tried to find the commit history or any way to find a cached or other version of the files

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need my help anymore but maybe others are.

In my understanding (as I was not able to gather much information from documentation) undo commit rebases you to detached head.

So in order for you to restore local files do the following:

- **git reflog** here search for the last know good commit (you can find it
  by commit message) and copy it's hash e.g. 1cf0e38
- **git checkout your    hash** git will inform you that you are in
  detached head
- **git ls-files**    and check if all files presented in commit
- **git switch -c new branch    name** in order to create new    branch
  to    retain commit and finally
- **git    push --set-upstream    origin    new    branch name**

After this you can merge new branch in desired one and continue working. Hope it helps.